# Javascript Vertical alphabetical order naviguation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, vertical-scrolling

I would like to create a javascript based alphabetical navigation like this one from a brasilian lyrics website [letras](https://www.letras.mus.br/cristiano-araujo/)

Can anyone explain me the concept behind ? BIG THX IN ADVANCE

Comment: Put your list into an array, and use arrayname.sort().

Comment: but how to link the list with the alphabetical bar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [example site](https://www.letras.mus.br/cristiano-araujo/cifras.html) vertical scroll is implemented using scrollspy  plug in
So as per example below, it is customized based on your use using bootstrap scrollspy

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      position: relative;
  }
  ul.nav-pills {
      top: 20px;
      position: fixed;
  }
  div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 250px;
      font-size: 28px;
  }
  #section1 {color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
    #section1, #section2, #section3, #section41, #section42  {
        margin-left: 150px;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">

A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">C</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">D <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#section41">DE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section42">DF</a></li>                     
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="section1">    
        <h1>A</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section2"> 
        <h1>B</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>        
      <div id="section3">         
        <h1>C</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section41">         
        <h1>Der </h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>      
      <div id="section42">         
        <h1>DF sagvsd</h1>
        <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome !! thanx a lot